# How to define default endpoints in custom provider?

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating custom terraform provider based on aws terraform provider.
I'd like to change "endpoints" block to static block of endpoints:

```
HOW AWS USES ENDPOINTS:

func New(ctx context.Context) (*schema.Provider, error) {
    provider := &schema.Provider{
        // This schema must match exactly the Terraform Protocol v6 (Terraform Plugin Framework) provider's schema.
        // Notably the attributes can have no Default values.
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            ...
            "endpoints": endpointsSchema(),
            ...
        },
    }

func endpointsSchema() *schema.Schema {
    endpointsAttributes := make(map[string]*schema.Schema)

    for _, serviceKey := range names.Aliases() {
        endpointsAttributes[serviceKey] = &schema.Schema{
            Type:        schema.TypeString,
            Optional:    true,
            Default:     "",
            Description: "Use this to override the default service endpoint URL",
        }
    }

    return &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeSet,
        Optional: true,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: endpointsAttributes,
        },
    }
}
```

I'd like endpoints block to be optional. If they're not provided, then default values should be used (env variable at first and static string only after). If endpoints are provided, then they're overriding these values:

```
HOW I'D LIKE TO USE THEM:

func New(ctx context.Context) (*schema.Provider, error) {
    provider := &schema.Provider{
        // This schema must match exactly the Terraform Protocol v6 (Terraform Plugin Framework) provider's schema.
        // Notably the attributes can have no Default values.
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            ...
            "endpoints": {
               Type:     schema.TypeSet,
               Optional: true,
               Elem: &schema.Resource{
                  Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                     "firstapiendpoint": {
                        Type:     schema.TypeString,
                        Optional: true,
                        DefaultFunc: schema.MultiEnvDefaultFunc([]string{"firstapi_URL"}, "https://firstapi.test"),
                     },
                     "secondapiendpoint": {
                        Type:     schema.TypeString,
                        Optional: true,
                        DefaultFunc: schema.MultiEnvDefaultFunc([]string{"second_URL"}, "https://second.test"),
                     },
                     "thirdapiendpoint": {
                        Type:     schema.TypeString,
                        Optional: true,
                        DefaultFunc: schema.MultiEnvDefaultFunc([]string{"third_URL"}, "https://third.test"),
                     },
            },
        },
    },

  },
}
```

Is that possible to make such changes without re-writing tons of code?